# TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable (Attempting linear regression via sklearn)

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm pretty new to python so I've adapted code that I've found in online resources to try to create this regression.  The code that I'm pulling from is working perfectly and I've barely changed anything but the data sources, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be incredible!
Here's the code I'm using:

```py
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    import numpy as np
    
    from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
    
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
    
    
    
    
    dfgmatgpa = df[["GradGPA", "GMATscore"]]
    
    dfgmatgpa = dfgmatgpa.dropna()
    
    dfgmatgpa.head()
```

```
GradGPA GMATscore

17  2.80000 340.0

18  2.80000 340.0

32  4.15000 660.0

36  3.88143 570.0

41  3.28571 540.0
```

```py
    # Load the diabetes dataset
    gmatgpa_X, gmatgpa_y = dfgmatgpa(return_X_y=True)
    
    # Use only one feature
    gmatgpa_X = gmatgpa_X[:, np.newaxis, 2]
    
    # Split the data into training/testing sets
    gmatgpa_X_train = gmatgpa_X[:-20]
    
    gmatgpa_X_test = gmatgpa_X[-20:]
    
    # Split the targets into training/testing sets
    gmatgpa_y_train = gmatgpa_y[:-20]
    
    gmatgpa_y_test = gmatgpa_y[-20:]
    
    # Create linear regression object
    regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    
    # Train the model using the training sets
    regr.fit(gmatgpa_X_train, gmatgpa_y_train)
    
    # Make predictions using the testing set
    gmatgpa_y_pred = regr.predict(gmatgpa_X_test)
    
    # The coefficients
    print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
    # The mean squared error
    print('Mean squared error: %.2f'
          % mean_squared_error(gmatgpa_y_test, gmatgpa_y_pred))
    # The coefficient of determination: 1 is perfect prediction
    print('Coefficient of determination: %.2f'
          % r2_score(gmatgpa_y_test, gmatgpa_y_pred))
    
    # Plot outputs
    plt.scatter(gmatgpa_X_test, gmatgpa_y_test,  color='black')
    
    plt.plot(gmatgpa_X_test, gmatgpa_y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=3)
    
    plt.xticks(())
    
    plt.yticks(())
    
    plt.show()
```

error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-321-b5f145507243> in <module>
----> 1 gmatgpa_X, gmatgpa_y = dfgmatgpa(return_X_y=True)
      2 
      3 # Use only one feature
      4 gmatgpa_X = gmatgpa_X[:, np.newaxis, 2]
      5 

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: `dfgmatgpa` is a dataframe. `dfgmatgpa(return_X_y=True)` implies it is a function (aka a callable). You probably want `dfgmatgpa[return_X_y=True]`

Comment: Did you intend to call some kind of load function?

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes sense.  The code that I'm basing my work off of was loading a dataset from sklearn to create the example.  I'm trying to figure out how to use my own dataset, dfgmatgpa, and assign the X and y values.  When I just try to define them:
gmatgpa_X = dfgmatgpa.GMATscore

gmatgpa_y = dfgmatgpa.GradGPA
I get the error:
IndexError: too many indices for array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are referring to some sample code like this:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
data = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
```

Here the `load_iris()` is a function, and when return_X_y is True, it returns a (data, target) tuple.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html

In your case you are defining `dfgmatgpa` as a dataframe, not a function, that's why you got the error. But you can define X and y separately as the way you needed: `gmatgpa_X` as the dataframe, `gmatgpa_y` as the target list.

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes sense. The code that I'm basing my work off of was loading a dataset from sklearn to create the example. I'm trying to figure out how to use my own dataset, dfgmatgpa, and assign the X and y values. When I just try to define them: gmatgpa_X = dfgmatgpa.GMATscore gmatgpa_y = dfgmatgpa.GradGPA I get the error: IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: It looks like your input is looking for array? Maybe try to convert the series to array "dfgmatgpa.GradGPA.values", (given that dfgmatgpa is a dataframe, dfgmatgpa.GradGPA would be Series).

Comment: That did it!!!  Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!!